# Can't compare file.readline() line with a string

Tags: python, text

im trying to compare a line from my `file.readline` with a string but this ain't working. I'm reading an html file which i need to parse to send the  section to a dictionary but when i use an if to compare one of the lines with a string it doesn't return True when they match.

Here is the code:

```
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    if (line == '<TEXT>'):
        while (line != '</TEXT>'):
            body += line + ' '
    content['text' + str(i)] = body
    i += 1
    body = ''
```

Comment: and if you use `for line in f.readline()` ?

Comment: Can you give an example of an such HTML file?

Comment: Have you tried `line.strip()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because its reading new line character in the string try:

```
for line in f:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if (line == '<TEXT>'):
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parsing the html by yourself, take a look at [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) built-in python html parser (or [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html) for python 2).

It will probably be easier and more robust than any code you will write by your own.

The example from the python documentation:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print("Encountered a start tag:", tag)

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        print("Encountered an end tag :", tag)

    def handle_data(self, data):
        print("Encountered some data  :", data)

parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed('<html><head><title>Test</title></head>'
        '<body><h1>Parse me!</h1></body></html>')
```

To use this example just add a member to the class which keeps track of the `content` you have.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure 'line' object does not have spaces at the beginning and at the end. You can strip it and then compare.

Because,

`x='<TEXT>'` is not equal to `y='<TEXT>    '`

Use `line = line.strip()` and then compare.