# Python If == true statement only working on last line of readline

Tags: python, file

My function only says that the last word in a file of words is an anagram (the first helper function). But every word in the file is an anagram of the word I tested and returns true independently with the helper function outside of the main function. I am not sure if it has something to do with `/n` being a part of the string, and then it accounting for that, but I tried putting in an if statement saying to delete it if it was in there and that did not work either. I also did test to make sure it is running through each word in the `.txt` file and it is.

```
def is_anagram(string1, string2):
    """Returns True if the two strings are anagrams of eachother.

    str, str -> bool"""
    if sorted(string1)==sorted(string2):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def find_anagrams(word):
    final = []
    content = open("small_list.txt")
    content.close
    while True:
        line = content.readline()
        print(line)
        if is_anagram(word, line) == True:
            print("bruh")
            final.append(line)
        elif line == '':
             break
    return final
```

Comment: Seems you are closing the content, before you are reading it.

Comment: What is the purpose of `content.close`?

Comment: Also FYI `if blah: return True else: return False` is equivalent to simply `return blah`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't compare file.readline() line with a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43950757/cant-compare-file-readline-line-with-a-string)

Comment: Closed that as a duplicate of this. ^

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ sounds good

Comment: @Julien `return bool(blah)`

Comment: @detly in the general case yes, but here blah is already a bool...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected, based on the method you use to read a line (`file.readline`). From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects):

> `f.readline()` reads a single line from the file; a newline character
>   (`\n`) is left at the end of the string, and is only omitted on the last
>   line of the file if the file doesn’t end in a newline.

Your `line` has a trailing newline, but `word` certainly does not. So, in the end, all you'd need to change is:

```
line = content.readline().rstrip()
```

Well, that's all you'd need to change to *get it working*. Additionally, I'd also recommend using the `with...as` context manager to handle file I/O. It's good practice, and you'll thank yourself for it.

```
with open("small_list.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if is_anagram(word, line.rstrip()):
            ... # do something here
```

It's better to use a `for` loop to iterate over the lines of a file (rather than a `while`, it's cleaner). Also, there's no need to explicitly call `f.close()` when you use a context manager (you're not currently doing it, you're only referencing the method without actually calling it).

---

Incorporating @Christian Dean's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49185754/python-if-true-statement-only-working-on-last-line-of-readline?noredirect=1#comment85377159_49185773) in this answer, you can simplify your anagram function as well - call `sorted` *and* return the result in a single line:

```
def is_anagram(a, b):
    return sorted(a) == sorted(b)
```

Comment: Also just a note to the OP: your anagram function could simply be `def is_anagram(a, b): return sorted(a) == sorted(b)`.

Comment: Ah shoot, you're right @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ. I forgot `set`s rids dups. Updated.